# add days blocking days of week from array Momentjs

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs

I'm in a trouble. I wanna know the final date from specific date using momentjs increasing certain amount of days and excluding the days of the week from array.

Example:

I have the date '2015-07-05'. I want to add 8 days for that date. So my final date is '2015-07-09'.

But I wanna exclude some days of the week that I have in this array: [1,5,6,7] (corresponding to "monday", "friday", "saturday" and "sunday" in ISO format).

After excluding those week days, my final date must be '2015-07-21' at the end. But I can't figure out how to solve it.

This is a function made for excluding saturdays, and sundays. But I can't adapt it to my scenario.

```
getFinalDate: function( date, days, excluded ){
            var increment = days / Math.abs( days );
            var addition = Math.ceil( Math.abs(days) / 5 ) * 7 * increment;
            var date = moment( date ).add( addition, 'days' );
            var remaining = days % 5;

            var date = moment( date ).add( addition, 'days' );

            while(remaining != 0) {
                date.add(increment, 'days');
                if( $.inArray( date.isoWeekday(), excluded ) == -1 )
                    remaining -= increment;
            }

            return date.format( 'YYYY-MM-DD' );

        }
```

the above function was taken from another publication. It works perfect but I need to exclude array of week days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I redid the function for you with slightly simpler logic.

Here is the code:

```
function getFinalDate(date, days, excluded) {
    var increment = days / Math.abs(days),
        i = 1,
        date = moment(date);
    excluded = excluded || [];
    do {
        date.add(increment, 'days');
        if (excluded.indexOf(date.isoWeekday()) === -1) {
            i++;
        }
    } while (i < Math.abs(days));
    return date.format('YYYY-MM-DD');
}
```

The idea is that you keep adding or subtracting 1 day until you have done more than the specified amount of `days`. If after you add or subtract the day, though, the `isoWeekday()` value is in your list of excluded days, don't count that as one of the *n* days.

There may be an off-by-one error in this, you will need to unit test it thoroughly, but this should get you on the right track.

Comment: Thanks a lot @GregL. I'm gonna test it but all your logic seems to be right.